# Sugar daddy allowance with Bitcoin

Tags: banking, scams, cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy

I met guys online as sugar daddies without sugar. I have never given my bank password but some guys request that I buy Google Play gift cards and I answered I wouldn’t use my cash for it. The guy said

> I would be sending your allowance from my bitcoin wallet baby... so whenever I send you your allowance I would also send you some more money so you can get me Google Play cards with them so I can invest in my Bitcoin wallet account and I would be able to spoil you more baby... remember you will be getting the Google Play cards with my money not yours

And other said

> I’m gonna write you a check of 2000 babe you can hold 500 I want you to please help me to make an w transfer to one of my friend there babe

He asked me transfer to his co worker. It sounds strange. Are these scams?

Comment: Yes, always a scam. If someone wants to give you money they can do so without weird requirements. There are so many legitimate and easy ways for them to send money that anything else is clearly a scam.

Comment: @HartCO " here are so many legitimate and easy ways".  Of course a **sugar daddy** wants to hide how send money to his mistress... (That doesn't mean this guy is legitimate.)

Comment: @RonJohn Sending bitcoin is fine and anonymous enough, it's that they always have some next step rather than just sending money.

Comment: @HartCO but that's not what you wrote in your original comment.

Comment: @RonJohn Not sure I follow, was just addressing your anonymous requirement. The weird requirements are the next steps they invariably have.

Answer (score 8):

> so you can get me goggle play cards
>
> I want you to please help me to make an w transfer to one of my friend there babe

These are classic signs of scams.

As a guy, **the only purpose** for being an **on-line** "Sugar Daddy" is to to scam the gullible, since an actual Sugar Daddy is going to want to **see and touch** her.

Comment: lol, exactly, if you're not providing sugar you're no sugar baby.

Comment: The frequency of these questions has me concerned for society.

Answer (score 6):

The scammer is likely just name-dropping Bitcoins as a confidence trick and then does the usual scam of sending you bad checks which get reversed a couple days after you cash them.

But assuming the unlikely case that you actually receive bitcoins from their bitcoin wallet to your bitcoin wallet. This is an irreversible transfer, so the check scam wouldn't work. In that case **you are likely being used for money laundering**. The bitcoins are from some illegal source (drug trading, obtained through hacking, whatever). Bitcoin transactions can be traced from wallet to wallet, so whoever trades the bitcoins into "real" money will soon get a visit from the police. You turn the bitcoins into anonymous gift cards and the criminals sell these gift cards. This conceals the flow of money for the criminals and turns it into money they can safely use to pay their bills.

Answer (score 3):

You asked,

> These are scam?

Yes, they are scams.

Generally, they will play out in one of two ways:

- The sugar daddy will send you money in a way that is reversible, then ask you to send some back in a way that is not reversible. Once you've bought the gift cards (or sent the wire transfer, or whatever) they will secretly reverse the original transaction. This will remove the money from your account which you've already spent! You will be left on the hook, the bank will come after you to collect the money.
- The sugar daddy is using you to launder money, by having you send it along by means that are not traceable back to them. Criminals are happy to lose a percentage of their finances in order to remain hidden. By pumping money through you, there is no paper trail that ties them to the money. So, when their criminal activity is eventually discovered by law enforcement, **you will be held responsible** since the transactions will be through your bank account. So - even if they never actually steal money from you, you may still be involved in a (dangerous) scam.